# I am implementing a project where I have to accept all the url requests

Tags: javascript, html

For example,

If the base url is example.com which serves index.html as response and if the request is example.com/path, I have to return index.html as response. I know using a web framework will solve this issue, but I want to do it in pure javascript.

Edit:
If the base url is example.com then if I enter example.com/hello or example.com/world or example.com/anything in the browser url bar, i have to return the same index.html page.

Comment: I think your question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: A system that accepts requests is called a "web server".  One that accepts *all* requests is still called that.  You can have a web server written in JavaScript.  Google "javascript web server"

Comment: @Amy don't forget to vote to close

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading up about Single Page Applications ( SPA ), like this https://medium.com/@pshrmn/single-page-applications-and-the-server-32a23d67936

In a nutshell, what you need is to know, what type of webserver your example.com is running. From that you need to configure all traffic to hit your example.com/index.html

If it is Apache2, then for instance, you could create a .htaccess file with something in the lines of this

```
RewriteEngine On
# set the base URL prefix
RewriteBase /
# for requests for index.html, just respond with the file
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
# if requested path is not a valid filename, continue rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if requested path is not a valid directory, continue rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if you have continue to here, respond with index.html
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

or if nginx, then you would write a configuration with  something like

```
server {
  ...
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

But still there are a lot of loose ends, to give a precise answer here